# PhoneGap: Get orientation of captured video?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ffmpeg

Is it possible know the orientation that the video was shot in? (portrait vs landscape)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [`Capture MediaFileData` API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#MediaFileData) you can access the `sizes of the media.

`width / height < 1` is portrait otherwise landscape.